# Implementing a node class for a binary tree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, nodes

I've got to implement a form of `binary tree` where it shows a hierarchy of employment where a boss is the trees root and a lesser employee is the left node and the right node is an employee of the same level. Employees on the same level are placed in accordance to their employee number.

```
public class Node {
private Person data;
private Node seniorEmployee;
private Node nextEmployee;
private Node lesserEmployee;

public Node(Member data, Node seniorEmployee) {
    this.data = data;
    this.seniorEmployee = seniorEmployee;
    this.nextEmployee = null;
    this.lesserColleague = null;
}

public Member getPerson() {
    return this.data;
}

public Node getSeniorEmployee() {
    return this.seniorEmployee;
}

public Node getNextEmployee() {
    return this.nextEmployee;
}

public Node getLesserEmployee() {
    return this.lesserEmployee;
}

public void setEmployee(Person e1) {
    if (nextEmployee == null) {
        nextEmployee = new Node(e1, this.seniorEmployee);
    } else {
        if (e1.compareTo(nextEmployee.getPerson()) > 0) {

    } else {

    }
}

public void setLesserEmployee(Member p1) {
    if (lesserEmployee == null) {
        lesserEmployee = new Node(e1, this.seniorEmployee);
    } else {
        if (e1.compareTo(lesserEmployee.getPerson()) > 0) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

This is what I've managed to do so far, but I do not know how to implement the set methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be ok for the employee of the same level:

```
public void setEmployee(Person e1) {
if (nextEmployee == null) {
    nextEmployee = new Node(e1, this.seniorEmployee);
} else {
    nextEmployee.setEmployee(e1);
}
```

}